# use aspnet_regiis in .NET core app, or find a different way to give access to a windows rsa key to a specific user

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, iis, encryption

Im actually migrating a .NET framework app to .NET 7.

This app was generating RSA key used for encrypting and decrypting files

The code was in two steps :

- generate the key with c# code (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/how-to-store-asymmetric-keys-in-a-key-container)
- grant access to the key to a specific user. Because some encryption/decryption will be also made by a web app running in iis under the user we want give the right to the key. This user is usually a different one than the account which will be use to generate the key

for that it seem there is no c# option, actually the code was using a call to aspnet-regiis  with Process.Start

```
var lRuntime = System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeDirectory();
var lFile = Path.Combine(lRuntime, "aspnet_regiis.exe");
Process.Start(lFile + " -pa \"MyKey\" \"MyUser\"...
```

Because this code was executed on a windows server with the .net framework installed, we was sure aspnet_regiis was present

In .NET Core, this code cant work. aspnet_regiis is not part of .net core. and We can't be sure the .NET framework will be installed on the server.

There is two ways to solve that

- persist to use aspnet_regiis. I dont'know if there is a way to get a "portable" version of this tool, or i don't know because the app wil be deploy on a windows server with IIS, maybe it will always come with the .net framework (for now)
- find a different way to grant permission. For now i didn't found. it seem there is definitively nothing in RSACryptoServiceProvider to do that. i didn't find any other alternatives.

What do you think ?

do you have any ideas ?

thanks !

Comment: Do you want to stay with Windows or migrate to other operating systems?

Comment: @LexLi we target only windows for now, maybe in the future we will try to make it cross platforms but its too many work for now

Comment: Then "We can't be sure the .NET framework will be installed on the server" is an invalid assumption in most cases, as .NET Framework 4.x is installed on almost all Windows Server releases supported by Microsoft today (except Nano Server which of course is rarely used now).

Comment: @LexLi hum are you sure about that ? maybe preinstalled but it need to be activate with Server Manager and select Features right ? If its the case its really not convenient, i can't justify .net framework need to be install on the server to make my .net core app working properly. A proper C# solution in .NET 7 would be perfect. I can't believe i have to rely on this tool, i think i will ask directly microsoft on their github see if they have proper solutions.

Comment: .NET Framework is required by Windows itself (such as IIS Manager), so you don't need to activate anything else.

Comment: @LexLi OK you certainly right, at least for the next years. I keep anyway this issue open as this solution is definitively not perfect and i would like to not depend of an external tool.